# How can I extend rich-editor filament php form component and add a custom button that fetches data via an API and updates the richtext editor with it?

Tags: php, laravel, alpine.js, laravel-filament

I am trying to extend the rich-editor filament form component and add a custom button that fetches data via an API and updates the rich text editor with it. I have added the button to rich-editor.blade.php, but I am not sure how to proceed with fetching data and updating the editor.

Rich Editor component Path:
vendor/filament/forms/resources/views/components/rich-editor.blade.php

My Custom Toolbar Option (button) in rich-editor.blade.php

```
@if ($hasToolbarButton(['noteOption']))
<button wire:click="dispatchFormEvent('init::cnotes', '{{ $getStatePath() }}', '{{ $getId() }}')">
    Get Latest Notes
</button>
@endif
```

Rich Editor Component

```
class RichEditor extends Field implements Contracts\CanBeLengthConstrained, Contracts\HasFileAttachments
{
    // ...

    protected array | Closure $toolbarButtons = [
        'attachFiles',
        'blockquote',
        'bold',
        'bulletList',
        'codeBlock',
        'h2',
        'h3',
        'italic',
        'link',
        'orderedList',
        'redo',
        'strike',
        'undo',
        'cnotes'
    ];

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->registerListeners([
            'init::cnotes' => [
                function ($component, string $statePath, string $uuid): void {

                    if ($component->isDisabled()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if ($statePath !== $component->getStatePath()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // I was able to get the current value of texteditor using 
                    dump($component->getState());

                    //this function fetches the latest company information as text 
                    $notes = $this->fetchCompanyNotes();

                    // I want to update the texteditor with this new $notes data I receive
                    // the below code doesn't work
                    $component->setState($notes);

                },
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this one out?